# Windows 上で正規表現を使ってファイルをリネームしたい

Tags: windows, 正規表現

Windows 上で正規表現でファイル名を一括変換するようなバッチを書きたいのですが
ふだん Linux 上でしかプログラムしたことがなく文字コード関係でつまずいてうまくいきません

```rb
files = Dir.entries('.')
files.each{|f|
  rename = f.gsub(/のコピー/, '')
  if f != rename
    puts "#{f} => #{rename}"
  end
}
```

最初にこのようにリネーム候補を出力するようにかいてみたんですが

```
./rename.rb:5:in 'gsub': incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with Windows-31J string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

というエラーになります

そのあと文字コード関係でいろいろ検索してみてソースの最初に

```
# encoding: Shift_JIS
```

をいれてみたのですが特にエラー変化がありません

次に正規表現のパターンの文字コードを指定する

```
/のコピー/s
```

とパターンのあとに s とかいてみたところ

```
./rename.rb:6: regexp encoding option 's' differs from source encoding 'Shift_JIS'
```

というエラーに変化しましたが先ほどソースコード1行目に Shift_JIS を指定したのになぜエラーになるのかがわかりません

べつに Ruby である必要もなく
Python と node.js もはいってるので
Windows で文字コードを気にすることなく
簡単に正規表現でファイルをリネームする方法があれば教えてほしいです

bash があればもっと簡単だったんですが…

---

回答いただいた内容にコメントでは書ききれないので追記させていただきます

PowerShell を使ってみました

```
$files = Get-ChildItem .
foreach ($f in $files) {
  $rename = $f.Name -replace 'のコピー', ''
  if ($f.Name -ne $rename) {
    # Rename-Item $f $rename
    echo "$f => $rename"
  }
}
```

いきなりリネームされないように echo するだけに書き換えて（あってるかもわからないですが）
rename.ps1 という名前で保存

右クリック PowerShell で実行
一瞬窓が立ち上がるんですが何も表示されずに終了します

貼り付けて実行すると何も表示されません

リネームだったら動くのかもしれないんですが
1度どのファイルがどういう名前になるか
確認したいので echo でデバッグした出力を確認したいです

で編集というのを選んでみると powershell ISE というのが起動して
そこでデバッグ >> 実行を選んだところ

```
PS *****\rename.ps1
このシステムではスクリプトの実行が無効になっているため、ファイル *****\rename.ps1 を読み込むことができません。詳細については、「about_Execution_Policies」(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170) を参照してください。
    + CategoryInfo          : セキュリティ エラー: (: ) []、ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

(パス名はユーザ名が入ってるのでふせています)

[PowerShellスクリプティングの第一歩（後編） (1/5) - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0709/20/news125.html)

この記事によると

> PowerShellではセキュリティ上の理由から、デフォルトでスクリプトの実行が無効に設定されている。そのため、スクリプト・ファイルを実行するためには、あらかじめPowerShellのスクリプト実行ポリシーを変更しておく必要がある。実行ポリシーを変更するにはSet-ExecutionPolicyコマンドレットを利用する。
>
> PS > Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

とあるのでこれを実行してみたんですが

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\powershell.config.json' is denied.
To change the execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. To change the execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".
```

と管理者権限での実行を要求されました

管理者権限を取得するには申請がいるので、この程度の作業内容では申請したくないというのが本音です

Comment: 参考までに、正規表現を使えるリネームソフトがあります。 https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/library/software/flexrenamer/

Comment: ありがとうございます。インストールしてみましたが正規表現を使うのに dry-runがみあたらないので少し怖いです。一応別フォルダにコピーというのはあるんですがサイズが多くてディスク残り容量的にいったん別の領域に置くというのも難しいです。

Comment: @chico さん、そのソフトはdry-runに相当する部分がそのままGUIで表示されているはずです。その内容を適用するかしないかは任意に決定できますよ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows付属のPowerShellの場合、Unicodeで動作するので文字コードを気にすることなく正規表現を使うことができます。

```
$files = Get-ChildItem .
foreach ($f in $files) {
  $rename = $f.Name -replace 'のコピー', ''
  if ($f.Name -ne $rename) {
    Rename-Item $f $rename
  }
}
```

このサンプルではわかりづらいですが、もちろん、[`-replace`は正規表現置換](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#replacement-operator)を行います。

Comment: 内容を ps1 ファイルで保存して rename 部分を echo にかえて実行してみたんですが、セキュリティエラーが出て動かないです。https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0709/20/news125.html　ここを少し読んでみたら最初にアドミン権限で power shell の起動が必要みたいで、権限は申請しないともらえないのでただリネームしたいだけでは申請したくないというのが本音です。せっかく回答いただいたのにすみません

Comment: @chico まずPowerShellプロンプトを開くことができ、提示のコードを張り付けた際は実行できるのでしょうか？ それが動作するなら、 `powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned スクリプトファイル` で実行できますか？

Comment: いきなりリネームされると困るので echo にかきかえてしまったんですが、何も表示されずに終わります

Comment: スクリプト自体は貼り付けると動きました。テストフォルダに「のコピー」にマッチするファイルがなかっただけでした。やりたいことはできそうです！　ありがとうございます